# tapping out of a view inside a tableview

Tags: uiview, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a UITableView that has a button and when a user long press the button a view will display with some reaction icons inside a UICollectionView (like facebook does) but I'm running into an issue.

ideally the user can just tap anywhere outside the view to make the view disappear but I'm not having luck with this, I added a tap recognizer to the tableview itself which does works, but then that totally kills the UICollection select event inside that view.

how can get it so the user can tap outside to hide the view without breaking another tap event?

Comment: could you put your code to make the question more clear?

Comment: You have several options, depending on how you want to approach things. One method would be to override `hitTest(...)` in the view holding the collection view. Another option would be to present a "popover" controller, which is automatically dismissed when tapped outside its frame... something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6foOO.png

Comment: ok cool, thanks I'll give this a shot.